# php script wont add record to mysql

Tags: php, mysql

The first example will add data to mysql database without any issue.  The second block of code - where I try to use variables wont. Can someone please explain where I am going wrong?

```
<?php
$query  = "INSERT INTO subjects (menu_name,position,visible) VALUES ('Edit me',4,1)";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
```

Problem CODE:

```
<?php
$menu_name = "TEST";
$position = 5;
$visible = 1;

$query  = "INSERT INTO subjects (menu_name,position,visible) 
           VALUES ('{menu_name}',{position}, {visible})";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
```

Comment: What happens if you use $visible and $position?  Are you getting any error messages?

Comment: why the curly brackets and no dollar sign ?

Comment: missing "`$`" on every single var inside the brackets. `{menu_name}` should be `{$menu_name}` and so on, despite you should first PREPARE the string before quering it. Parsing variables directly in the query is dangerous. read more: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php (BIND parameters)

Comment: Thank you so much for your comments. I really appreciate the help. Have absolutely no idea why I failed to add the "$". Woods and trees and all that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Answer updated with MySQLi prepare statement, thanks @h2ooooooo

```
<?php
//Open a new connection to the MySQL server
$db = new mysqli('host','username','password','database_name');

//Output connection errors
if ($db->connect_error) {
    die('Error : ('. $db->connect_errno .') '. $db->connect_error);
}

    $sql = "INSERT INTO subjects (menu_name, position, visible) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";

    if (!$stmt = $db->prepare($sql)) {
        echo 'Database prepare error';
        exit;
    }

    $stmt->bind_param('sss', $menu_name, $position, $visible);

    if (!$stmt->execute()) {
        echo 'Database execute error';
        exit;
    }

    $stmt->close();
```

I'd say for you to take a look in the many tutorials thorugh net, like these:

http://markonphp.com/simple-insert-mysqli/ and

http://www.sanwebe.com/2013/03/basic-php-mysqli-usage

Comment: I did not realise this being new to php and MySQL.  How do you "bind" variables to prevent malicious SQL statements?

Comment: Sorry, answer updated now. @RickTicky, take a look in the links also, step-by-step tutorials.

Comment: thanks very much!  The more I look into this issue, the more important it seems. I appreciate you taking the time to help me and I hope that one day I will have the experience to do the same for others.

Answer (score 0):

> $query  = "INSERT INTO subjects (menu_name,position,visible) VALUES
>   ('".$menu_name."','".$position."', '".$visible."')";

try this